# spring data redis deserialization not working

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I found an error while trying to cache using redis.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
public class  Human {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime;

    protected Human() {
    }

    public Human(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

```java
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "humanService::find", key = "#name")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Human getHuman(String name) {
        return humanRepository.findByName(name)
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
```

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }
}

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisConfig {

    private final RedisProperties redisProperties;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        final RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisProperties.getHost(), redisProperties.getPort());
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

and redis cache config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CacheConfig {

    private static final long DEFAULT_TTL_SECONDS = 600L;

    private final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return RedisCacheManager
            .builder(redisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(generateCacheConfig(Duration.ofSeconds(DEFAULT_TTL_SECONDS)))
            .build();
    }

    private RedisCacheConfiguration generateCacheConfig(Duration duration) {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(duration)
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                new StringRedisSerializer()))
            .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper)));
    }
}
```

There is no problem when serializing and inserting values ​​into redis, but when deserializing it, a casting exception occurs.

```
class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ...
```

Looking for the cause, when calling `_findRootDeserializer` in objectmapper, the type could not be found, so `UntypedObjectDeserializer` is being called.

The cause of this is definitely the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper). However, the moment the injected objectaMapper is subtracted, the jsr310 serialization fails.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ObjectMapper` tell Jackson to use an `ArrayList` to hold collections of `Human` instances like:

```
objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Human.class);
```